# Firebase DatabaseQuery stops getting called

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a DatabaseQuery that only works in the beginning and then it stops working. The observe doesn't get called anymore.

Anybody tried this?

```
Database.database().reference().child("someChild").queryOrdered(byChild: "someChild").queryEqual(toValue: "someValue").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
  print("called")
})
```

When I change something related to that "someChild" with updateChildValues like... 5 times.

```
Database.database().reference().child("someChild").updateChildValues(someDict)
```

It works 4 times and suddenly stops working.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are trying to do? What behavior are you expecting and what behavior is occurring. Also provide the query you are using and where/how you are calling it.

Comment: I added some code as examples

Answer (score 0):

I apparently removed all the observers related to my DatabaseReference at some point. That is why it didn't work.

I am now using handles instead, and it works.